# Server Side Call waits for Ajax completion - ASP Webform

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, webforms

After the form submission on ASP page I call this function for some background work.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "SomeService.asmx/LoadData",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ requestDto: { Type: "Type1" } }),
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //show toast message
        }
    });
```

The service is something like this

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public async Task<SomeReponseDto> LoadData(SomeRequestDto requestDto)
{
    var neededData = await GetDataFromDB();
    Session[requestDto.Type"_Data"] = neededData;
    return new SomeResponseDto
    {
        Status = true,
        Message = "Data for " + requestDto.Type.ToString() + " are ready."
    };
}
```

I want the above the work to be done in background and I need to store it in session because we can not use persistent data-base. The problem is after I submit for Type1, the service is hit and the processing will start. This will now block the UI and user can make changes. But if the User moves from Type1 to Type2 (same UI just different values for the form), it required a hit on serverside which waits for the ajax to complete. Can I make the ajax call independent to any server side calls. I am kind of new with server-side rendering so any help would be great.

Comment: I don't fully understand when you call this method. Is it called when the page is completes render (aka: ready?) . Or are you trying to call it during the postback??

We need some more info.

Comment: @SalikRafiq .After the postback for Submit, I call this function from client side ajax call. I just need this to not block any other postbacks after. Any Ajax call after the 1st one is independent and will work just fine but any postback call will wait for the Ajax to complete. Is it because the page is "reloaded". I don't have much experience in Webforms(disclaimer)

Comment: You realise that when you submit in webforms the page will get reloaded any scripts running will terminate - so if you call this after the submit it will get terminated. What you will need to do is generate this code so that onLoad - on the client side - this will execute.